# Predsort/3 like msort/2

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I would like to know is it possible to use `predsort/3` without losing duplicate values? If not, that how should I sort this list of terms?

**Current sort function:**

```
compareSecond(Delta, n(_, A, _), n(_, B, _)):-
        compare(Delta, A, B).
```

**Result:**

```
predsort(compareSecond, [n(3, 1, 5), n(0, 0, 0), n(8, 0, 9)], X).
X = [n(0, 0, 0), n(3, 1, 5)].
```

You see, that term `n(8,0,9)` is gone and that's not what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`predsort` *will* remove duplicates, but it leaves it to the comparison predicate to define which elements are duplicates. Adapt your `compareSecond` predicate to also compare the first and third arguments to the functors it receives, if the second argument compares equal.

Alternatively, switch to `msort`:

```
?- maplist(swap_1_2, [n(3, 1, 5), n(0, 0, 0), n(8, 0, 9)], Swapped),
|    msort(Swapped, SortedSwapped),
|    maplist(swap_1_2, Sorted, SortedSwapped).
% snip
Sorted = [n(0, 0, 0), n(8, 0, 9), n(3, 1, 5)] .
```

where the definition of `swap_1_2` is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not bothered about further sorting the duplicates, this simple addition prevents them from being removed.

```
compareSecond(Delta, n(_, A, _), n(_, B, _)):-
    A == B;
    compare(Delta, A, B).
```

Comment: This works, but you'll need to add a cut after predsort. =>
predsort(), !. Otherwise, you will get other results from the OR operator.