# Possible behaviors of `predsort/3`

Tags: list, sorting, prolog, compare, stable-sort

This is a followup to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070482/how-to-sort-a-list-by-the-second-atom-in-functor-prolog/28070866#28070866) to a question about sorting on a particular argument of a term, without creating a new list for a `keysort` (if I understood the original question correctly).

Say we wanted `predsort/3` to behave exactly as `sort/2`: if I understand correctly, this would mean calling it as:

```
?- predsort(compare, List, Sorted).
```

Now say that we wanted to use `predsort/3` to sort as implemented by `msort/2` (see also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247032/prolog-predsort-3-like-msort-2)). One way to do it would be to define a comparison predicate `Pred(-Delta, +A, +B)` that does not unify `Delta` with `=` when the elements are actually equal:

```
mcompare(Delta, A, B) :-
    compare(Delta0, A, B),
    (   Delta0 == (=)
    ->  Delta = (<)
    ;   Delta = Delta0
    ).

?- predsort(mcompare, List, Sorted).
```

**Question**: does that really simply sort without removing duplicates, as `msort/2` does? It seems like it should.

Moving on: say we wanted to sort terms with arity > n, on the standard order of the nth argument in the term. The clean way to do it would be:

```
sort_argn(N, List, Sorted) :-
    map_list_to_pairs(arg(N), List, Pairs),
    keysort(Pairs, Sorted_pairs),
    pairs_values(Sorted_pairs, Sorted).
```

If we wanted to use `predsort/3` to achieve the same effect, we could try using a comparison predicate as follows:

```
compare_argn(N, Delta, A, B) :-
    arg(N, A, AN),
    arg(N, B, BN),
    compare(Delta, AN-A, BN-B).
```

And to sort on the second argument:

```
?- predsort(compare_argn(2), List, Sorted).
```

However, this is *not the same* as `sort_argn/3` above that uses `keysort/2`. It will remove duplicates, and it will order compound terms according to the standard order of the original full term if the second arguments of two terms happen to be equal:

```
?- predsort(compare_argn(2), [f(b,2), f(a,1), f(a,1), f(a,2)], Sorted).
Sorted = [f(a, 1), f(a, 2), f(b, 2)].

?- sort_argn(2, [f(b,2), f(a,1), f(a,1), f(a,2)], Sorted).
Sorted = [f(a, 1), f(a, 1), f(b, 2), f(a, 2)].
```

Making the *assumption* that for every pair of `A` and `B` passed to the comparison predicate `Pred(Delta, A, B)`, `A` comes before `B` in the original list. Can we define a comparison:

```
compare_argn_stable(N, Delta, A, B) :-
    arg(N, A, AN),
    arg(N, B, BN),
    compare(Delta0, AN, BN),
    (   Delta0 == (=)
    ->  Delta = (<)
    ;   Delta = Delta0
    ).
```

At this point, **if and only if** any two elements `A` and `B` are always passed to the comparison predicate in the same order as they were in the original list, this should behave identically to `sort_argn/3` above:

```
?- predsort(compare_argn_stable(N), List, Sorted).
```

Now of course it is important that `compare_argn_stable/4` unifies `Delta` with `<` when the two "keys" are equal. Furthermore, the behavior is implementation dependent, and only identical to the `keysort` example iff `predsort/3` keeps the original order of elements when passing them to the comparison predicate.

**Question** Is that correct?

**Question** Is there any standard that covers this aspect of `predsort/3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since no one has answered, and since I am quite certain about it now:

Yes, you could use `predsort/3` to emulate any of the other sorts. The question describes in some detail how.

**However**: this is a bad idea for several reasons.

- The "stability" depends on the implementation of `predsort/3` (see the question)
- The `predsort/3` itself is not part of any standard (as far as I can tell)
- The chances are, your Prolog implementation provides an `msort/2` or `keysort/2` that is far more efficient than `predsort/3`

There might be rare cases where the size of the elements of the list is much bigger than the length of the list we are sorting, and this little dance:

```
list_to_keyval_pairs(List, Pairs), % defined by the user as necessary
keysort(Pairs, Sorted_pairs),
pairs_values(Sorted_pairs, Sorted)
```

([see here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=keysort/2)) is actually more expensive (slower) than using `predsort(keycmp, List, Sorted)`, with `keycmp/3` defined by the user. Even then, the order of results with equivalent keys depends not only on the (user) definition of `keycmp/3`, but also on the implementation of `predsort/3`.

In other words, a "stable" sort with `predsort/3` is a bad idea.

Comment: I have given you examples of a hypothetical sort that works for a total order but does not work for your order ; that is, a sort that in some place compares A with B and in others compares B with A assuming that they are the opposite to each other. So imagine, that this sort sorts with A, B and then checks with B, A. It would loop for  `[a,a]`

Comment: @false Indeed. The (unwarranted) assumption that I am silently making throughout is that we are dealing with a `predsort` that keeps the original order of elements when passing them as the last two arguments to the first argument of `predsort/3`. I will incorporate this in my answer, if you don't feel like writing an answer yourself (which you will do better anyway).

Comment: Ideally, ask this question in a more general manner to get feedback from other groups on SO, but this **is** a big effort. I wanted once to extend a question to another language (SQL), but still have to found the time to make a good question... See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280348/how-to-handle-cross-language-questions-correctly

Comment: @false Prolog is generic enough I guess; would it be enough to show a `predsort/3` implementation that works as I assumed (say a merge sort), and a `predsort/3` implementation that loops on a list like `[a,a]` (or something small enough)? Which sorting algorithm would be susceptible to this problem?

Comment: @false Anyway, I am finally starting to see the reason for my confusion: `predsort/3`, as defined in the SWI-Prolog implementation, is a stable sort in disguise: it is a merge sort that discards an element when the comparison returns `=`. There is no reason for a merge sort to do that, or to swap the order of elements during comparison. If I am not wrong, a quicksort has plenty of opportunities to swap elements, so it is not "stable" as such.

Comment: The counterexample I gave does no require that the sorting is not stable. It simply needs to change the operands from time to time.

Comment: Calls to `predsort/3` can be optimized in a similar way as calls to other meta-predicates such as `maplist/2`. Just a question of writing the necessary `goal_expansion/2` clauses and use them to expand the calls.

Comment: @PauloMoura If I understood the comments of Jan correctly (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/swi-prolog/2MYJHbemplk/8w5kWdlvPIMJ) there is a bigger issue WRT efficiency in SWI-Prolog: a C implementation sorts "in place", avoiding term copying (which is fundamental because of how the "virtual machine" of SWI-Prolog is implemented, I assume?)

Comment: @Boris Yes but `predsort/3` is found on several other Prolog implementations. Also in Logtalk (as `sort/3`). Hope to work in the optimization I suggested soon.